# Grails test user account creation manually

Tags: grails

I am working in grails application, I was been asked to create a test user for our site. I did write the code in admin controller and gave the link in his page. The code worked and also I can see the details of this test user. But when I try to login using test user details, I am not able to login.

```
def createTestUser = {
    String timeStr = System.currentTimeMillis() + ''
    //def user = userService.createQuickUser(timeStr + '@test.supjam.com', timeStr, 'test-user') // TODO requires supajam-domain 2011.12.5.1
    def user = userService.createQuickUser(timeStr + '@test.supajam.com', 'test-user')
    user.passwd = timeStr
    user.dailyNews = false
    user.offers = false
    user.emailConfirmed = true
    user.enabled = true
    user.save(failOnError: true)
}
```

This was the code. If anybody can please help, I would be thankful to them.

Comment: Please show your userService code and login code

Comment: Do you mean by 'I can see the details of this test user' that the user is in the database?

Comment: i Got the solutions for this problem...........I was using spring security. And when adding test user I took the encryption so it was not able to match the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This similar question has some debugging tips:

[Grails spring security login issue: /auth?login_error=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859078/grails-spring-security-login-issue-authlogin-error-1)

i liked putting log.debug() statements in the authfail() if blocks.

```
if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
   msg = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.errors.login.expired
   log.debug "exception - ${msg}"   // added this
}
```